# Vue.js: Search bar component - how to make a reset button appear if input value length is > 1?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement, vue.js

I am in the process of making a search bar component. I have included a little cross button on the right which I want to appear if the users' input value length in the search field is bigger than 1.

This is what I have so far:

**Template**

```
    <template lang="pug">
    .search
        .search__wrapper
            form.search
                input#search__input(
                    type="search"
                    v-model="taskSearch"
                    placeholder="Search"
                )
                img(v-if="taskSearch.val.length < 1").resetText(src="../../assets/icons/cross-icon.svg")
</template>
```

---

I have tested the if statement with:

```
a: (v-if="0 < 1")
b: (v-if="2 < 1")
```

and it works perfectly - (a) hides the button and (b) makes it appear. I just don't know the Vue.js syntax to select the users' input value length from that specific field.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you look for length of the `taskSearch` since It's reactive ?

Comment: Tried that @BelminBedak, did not work...

Comment: Not sure what doesn't work, but `v-if="taskSearch.length"` should work without any problem.I don't work with pug so not sure does everything from that side ok.

Comment: @AKL012 Could you add that code to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

As @Belmin Bedak said remove the .val from your v-if. taskSearch is the value not the element.

Also, shouldnt it be greater than 0, e.g. v-if=“taskSearch.length > 0” since thats when you want to show it, when it has more characters than 0 (or 1 if thats what you really want, but it has to be greater than not less than).